# I'm trying to delete messages in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to delete the message I sent after 5 seconds

```js
msg.channel.send(Embed).then(messageReaction => {
    messageReaction.react("❌");
    messageReaction.react("✔️");
    messageReaction.delete(5000); // This line causes the error
```

But it doesn't work. This is the error I get:

```
> (node:54020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:501:44)  
    at C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:45:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you need to pass the options such as timeout and reason as an object so your solution is:

```js
messageReaction.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
```

Comment: still doesn't work, i tried this: `messageReaction.delete({ timeout: 5000, reason: "a"});` still didn't work

Comment: You're getting `Supplied options is not an object.`?

Comment: yeah i still am

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `.delete()` anywhere else in your file?

Comment: is that it? I do have it in one other place, let me try it now